# Does oversize lens for focusing small laser beam width affect the focal length of lens?

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, lenses

I am working with optical setup where I am focusing collimated light with 2" size lens. Beam width of collimated light is around 20 mm 1/e2 diameter. The focal length of focusing lens is 750mm. I expect to have focus position at around 750 mm. However I get laser light focus at 875mm. Therefore, I am curious to know that, if size of lens would can shift focus position further. Laser light wavelength is 2050 nm.

Comment: Is the 750 mm focal length for visible light?

Comment: The size of the lens does not matter. Most optical glasses work fine for the 2um range and their refractive index doesn't change enough to explain your observation. Are you by chance using a fused silica lens? That's one of the few optical materials that seem to have a large enough change in refractive index to go from 750mm to 875mm focal length.

Comment: @JohnDoty In manufacturer lens catalogue data, it mentioned Wavelength Range 185 nm - 2.1 μm. Therefore, I believe it is applicable for my application as I am also working in near infrared region.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes. I am using UV fused silica lens.

Comment: @HinaPatel What does the catalog say about the test conditions for the 750mm specification? Reality is in the testing, not in the print.